# /bin/sh script error "arithmetic expression: expecting primary: " + " "

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, openvpn, posix

ERROR:  `./client-disconnect.sh: 22: ./client-disconnect.sh: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: " + "`

I just need to know how to fix it.  It's for user accounting with OpenVPN.

Script

```
#!/bin/sh
# Copyright Josh Cepek
# This file is part of the openvpn-dynamic project, available from:
# https://github.com/QueuingKoala/openvpn-dynamic
# Dual-licensed under GPLv3 and BSD-3-clause

# BEGIN User Disconnect Accounting

log_file="/var/log/openvpn-disconnect.log"

# Be platform friendly to both GNU and BSD-userland:
if date --help >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    get_date() { date -d "@$1" +'%F-%H:%M'; }
else
    get_date() { date -r "$1" +'%F-%H:%M'; }
fi

# Vars used in log line:
#time:
date_from="$(get_date $time_unix)"
unix_to=$(($time_unix + $time_duration))
date_to="$(get_date $unix_to)"
time_h=$(($time_duration / 3600))
time_m=$(( $time_duration % 3600 / 60 ))
#bw:
bw_up="$(( $bytes_received / 1000**2 ))\
.$(( $bytes_received % 1000**2 / 1000 ))"
bw_down="$(( $bytes_sent / 1000**2 ))\
.$(( $bytes_sent % 1000**2 / 1000 ))"


# Format the line for export:
line="User '$common_name' \
using $ifconfig_pool_remote_ip \
from $trusted_ip:$trusted_port \
for $date_from to $date_to ($time_h:$time_m) \
BW(up/down) $bw_up/$bw_down"

# Append it to the log
echo "$line" >> "$log_file"

# END User Disconnect Accounting

exit 0
```

Comment: Where do you set the variable `time_unix` initially?

Comment: I tried changing time_unix to time_ascii as the env shows it as time_ascii.   after doing this I got the error  "date: invalid date '@'"  Thanks to a post down below I am getting the ENV printed in the log file.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the script expects several parameters which are set by OpenVPN in the environment variables like `time_unix` and `time_duration`, but they are missing.

You shouldn't directly run it.  Have you set up the script correctly as explained in [the document](https://github.com/QueuingKoala/openvpn-dynamic/blob/master/user-accounting/README.md)?  See also [OpenVPN manpage](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html).

You might want to add `printenv` to debug the script.  All available variables are dumped to the log file by this.

```
log_file="/var/log/openvpn-disconnect.log"
printenv >> "$log_file"
```

Comment: Yes I did set the script up, but it failed.  I was trying to figure out why.  It runs the connect script fine, but when I d/c no log is generated.

Comment: Strange.  See variables actually set (the answer updated).

Comment: I tried changing time_unix to time_ascii as the env shows it as time_ascii. after doing this I got the error "date: invalid date '@'" Thanks to a post down below I am getting the ENV printed in the log fil

Comment: `time_unix` is mandatory for that script to work.  Maybe it's incompatible with OpenVPN you're running.  You'd better edit your question and paste all the `printenv` output there.